# how to use queue when requests are parallel in laravel

Tags: laravel, queue

my function in controller Calling parallel and i create a job for use queue in laravel Because parallel call causing the problem

i call this job in my function :

```
$this->dispatch(new ProcessReferal($orderId));
```

and i run this command in terminal :

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=3
```

But my job is still running in parallel

And processes the process simultaneously

what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are checking it on Local server. Then, You have to add `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` in .env file.

`QUEUE_DRIVER=sync` is used for parallel call

Answer (score 1):

*Hi there,*

With queue laravel, you need config some info in your code:

See more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#connections-vs-queues

**First:**

- Driver: default sync, so you need change it to: **database**, **redis**...
  You can change it in .env file (QUEUE_DRIVER=database...)
- Connections: Very important if you setting driver is database and use mutil DB for your project.

**Second:**

- Laravel queue have some config, but i think we need see 3 thing: retry_after, timeout, tries. When you work with large job, retry_after and timeout is very important.

*Hope it can help you.*